# Selecting all rows where one column in a given range of columns evaluates to True (Numpy)

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following numpy array for instance:

```
data = np.array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1.,  1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.,  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.,],
                 [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,  0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.,],
                 [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.,  0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.,  1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,],
                 [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0.,  0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1.,  0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0.,],
                 [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,  0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.,],
                 [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,],
                 [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,]])
```

I want to select all rows where one of a given range of columns are true.
So each row where any of columns in `data[:,[1,2,5]]` (for instance) evaluates to True (1.) should be returned.

Do you have any suggestions?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Just use `any(1)` and slicing:

```
idx = data[:,[1,2,5]].any(1)
data[idx]
```

output:

```
array([[0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1.,
        0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Indexer:

```
>>> idx
array([False, False,  True,  True, False, False,  True])
# rows 2,3,6
```